# Where exactly were the British occupations in the Egypt Campaign?

Tags: 19th-century, napoleonic-wars

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murad_Bey) that Murad Bey would accept the British occupations in Alexandria Damietta and Rosetta.

> Murad had reportedly offered money to the French forces to leave Egypt and offered to ally himself with the British in exchange for allowing the British to occupy Alexandria, Damietta and Rosetta.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murad_Bey)

Britain did have an interest in having a colony in Egypt, which was also one of the goals of the British Egyptian Campaign in 1807. The Wikipedia page also says that Murad Bey would accept the British occupations in Alexandria and Rosetta.
It's hard for me to find a map that shows exactly how the British - French and Ottoman territories were organized in that region.

The actual quote from Wikipedia's [linked source](https://archive.org/details/00jrgo/page/138/mode/2up) is:

> ... and later offered to ally himself with the British, whom he would have allowed to occupy Alexandria, Damietta, and Rosetta. .... He died of the plague before he could conclude this agreement ....

Comment: The British were allied with the Ottomans at the time, so they didn't act as an occupying force and, consequently, didn't have any territory.

Comment: I know that they were allied but still they must have had some territories for them self. I know that Alexandria was one of them and the British even tried to reconquer the city in 1807.

Comment: I think you're using the word "territories" differently.  Allies don't have "territories" inside their allies countries. They might have encampments.  the US & UK are currently allies, but there are no UK territories inside US boundaries.

Comment: In this link it says that Murad Bey would accept the British occupations in Alexandria and Rosetta fe. British did have interest in having a colony in Egypt which is also one of the goals with the British Egypt Campaign in 1807. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murad_Bey

Comment: This is why it is important to include the quote, rather than "I have read" - this does not say that the British had territories, it says that Murad Bey **offered** territories.

Comment: I think it's a gray area - in practice the British troop had control over large regions in the Delta. Likewise the British and Americans had control over large parts of Western Europe after D-day in 1944-45. I simply want to know where in the Delta the British had control.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Well, yes and no. The US does have "territories" within British lands, BIOT being the best example.